# How to highlight the words from a vector in Wold Puzzle Game with SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to highlight the words of my array when the grid is shown in the app Canvas Screen.

I have implemented the following code, as you see below. I have built two functions of type bool; the first one is called findWordInDirection(), which define the direction of words in the grid. This function is called by the second function called findWord(), which is used as a ternary operator on the parent view to highlight the words of the vector in the grid. As you see in the code below, I have used print() function to understand the code, and as a result, it does an iteration only for the first word, and then it does not read the character from findWordInDirection() function. Any idea how I can solve this in order to obtain the goal?

```
import SwiftUI

struct WordSearchGameView: View {
    let wordsToFind = ["hello", "hay"]
    let gridSize = 5
    
    @State var grid: [[Character]] = [        ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"],
        ["a", "c", "c", "a", "i"],
        ["g", "i", "a", "h", "c"],
        ["h", "a", "o", "a", "l"],
        ["e", "o", "l", "y", "s"]
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            
            ForEach(0..<gridSize, id: \.self) { row in
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    
                    ForEach(0..<gridSize, id: \.self) { col in
                        
                            Text(String(grid[row][col]))
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                                .background(findWord(row: row, col: col) ? Color.yellow : Color.white)
                        }
                        
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
        Text(String(grid[3][2]))
    }
    
    func findWord(row: Int, col: Int) -> Bool {
        var count1 : Int = 0
        for word in wordsToFind {
            count1 += 1
            print("Finding word: \(word) and count1: \(count1)")
            if findWordInDirection(word: word, row: row, col: col, dir: (0, 1)) ||
               findWordInDirection(word: word, row: row, col: col, dir: (1, 0)) ||
               findWordInDirection(word: word, row: row, col: col, dir: (1, 1)) ||
               findWordInDirection(word: word, row: row, col: col, dir: (-1, 0)) ||
               findWordInDirection(word: word, row: row, col: col, dir: (0, -1)) ||
               findWordInDirection(word: word, row: row, col: col, dir: (-1, -1)) ||
               findWordInDirection(word: word, row: row, col: col, dir: (1, -1)) ||
               findWordInDirection(word: word, row: row, col: col, dir: (-1, 1)) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    
    func findWordInDirection(word: String, row: Int, col: Int, dir: (Int, Int)) -> Bool {
        if word.count > gridSize {
            return false
        }
        var r = row
        var c = col
        var count2 : Int = 0
      
        for char in stride(from: 0, through: word.count - 1, by: 1)  {
            count2 += 1
            print("char: \(char) and count2: \(count2)")
            if r < 0 || r >= gridSize || c < 0 || c >= gridSize || String(grid[r][c]) != String(word[word.index(word.startIndex, offsetBy: char)]) {
                return false
            }

            r += dir.0
            c += dir.1
        }
        return true
    }
}

struct WordSearchGameView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WordSearchGameView()
    }
}
```

Comment: `return true` here you exit the for loop and the function when you have found the first word. Maybe use a counter instead that you increase for each found word.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I replaced for with a while as you see ``` while count < word.count { ... count ++1} ``` but it again not worked.

Comment: I was referring to the findWord function if that wasn’t clear and I don’t think it’s the loop kind that is the issue but that you exit the loop to early.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. I am trying to understand the problem using debug but still I am stuck. For what I see the function findWord turns false in the first step and the app has color white in the place of h and yellow for all other letters. Do you think the problem might be with direction or I am wrong?